# Android adb logcat missing some logs during emulator booting

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-logcat

I met a weird issue when I tried to search some logs during emulator booting.
When I create an emulator, the adb device started with "offline" first, then I type

`adb logcat -v time | tee log1.txt`

and adb will keep "wait-for-device" until the adb became online.


Then when the emulator boots up, I type `adb logcat -v time | tee log2.txt` again except the destination of the log file.

Now, I use `vimdiff log1.txt log2.txt` to compare these two logs and found log1 missed many logs as Log_Diff

[image]


I have no idea why some logs in log1.txt will missed.
Any ideas?


P.S. I am using Android 5.1-64bit Emulator in sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, finally I found the root cause in Android log daemon.

The main problem is the LogBufferElement is using a CLOCK_MONOTONIC timestamp as the sorting index.

When the timestamp of the multiple LogBufferElement are the same, LogReader may only dump the last entry. That's why some logs seem being lost.

AOSP Android 5.1 still had this issue, but Android 6.0 had fixed it.
You can refer to this [patch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/f7c0f75275d0fde2d8b7614f1501f0ad0cd3a01c).

Btw, I also did some modification for this patch.

The main reason is Android 6.0 supports the C++ 11 atomic std libs, but Android 5.1 is not yet. Some the atomic APIs need to roll back. (e.g. atomic_fetch_add_explicit())